# What is the age of the driver?

Tags: logical-deduction

This is a simple and brilliant puzzle.

> You are driving a car from temple to home.
>
> The temple to home distance is 55km.
>
> The car moves at 60km/hrs.
>
> If it starts 8.32 am and reaches at home 9.27 am,
>
> So, What is the age of driver?

Comment: [​](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11564/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common and well known question. The answer is:

> My age, as it has been mentioned that "You are driving a car"

Comment: ...and is generally a better puzzle verbally.